# How to get source code from PyCodeObject in c python api?

Tags: c++, cpython

Hi i'm using c python api.
I want to extract function object's source code.
I want pure python code (like def func: ... ) But if it is hard then, i want to 
get py byte codes at least.

Here is my c++ code that i get PyCodeObject from PyFunctionObject.

```
//pObject is PyFunctionObject which is python standard lib's function.
PyFunctionObject* pFunctionObject = (PyFunctionObject*)pObject;

PyCodeObject* codeObject = (PyCodeObject*)pFunctionObject->func_code;

PyObject* strObject = codeObject->co_code; //get code from code object

char * sourceCode = PyString_AsString(strObject); //convert to string
```

But sourceCode variable(char*) always show only 1 byte.

How should i gonna get this?
There is a lot of ways to do this in python code side, like just use 'dis' or 'inspect' module.
But i want to do this by c python api.

P.S
I guess that the PyCodeObject's co_code member is an byte array.
I used visual studio debug memory view and saw co_code member's adjoined memory byte but it seems like a byte code array(just maybe).

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, `PyCodeObject->co_code` is the generated byte code, not pure Python source code.

In Python, we could use `inspect.getsource` to get pure Python source code. And in C, you could also use it via `PyObject_CallMethod`